# How to force refresh of a page by http server?

Tags: http, dynamic, nanohttpd

I have a small HTTP server in Java (based on NanoHTTPD) that is able to receive data from my application (currently playing track, play state and so on). It generates a nice web page with information received in notification, but is there a way for server to somehow ask remote web browser to reload the page when new notification arrives?

Answer (score 3):

Does that help you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events . It looks interesting! (and it is part of HTML 5 soon)

Answer (score 2):

i would either use a meta refresh tag that periodically refreshes the page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.yourdomain.xx/yourpage.php">
```

or add some javascript code that uses ajax to poll for new infos  and then display them on the page or perform
 a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Use the EventSource interface. It...

> is a web content's interface to server-sent events. An EventSource
>   instance opens a persistent connection to an HTTP server, which sends
>   events in text/event-stream format. The connection remains open until
>   closed by calling EventSource.close().

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource

This way, you won't have  useless boring refresh of page.

You have a working example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42076867/195812