# How to refresh a webpage remotely on other computers

Tags: javascript, browser, server

Lets say I have PC 1 and PC 2. 
PC 1 is located in Norway and PC 2 is located in USA. 
www.webpage.com is currently open on the web browser on PC 2.

Now on PC 1, I will change the background on the www.webpage.com color to red. I will change the css and save it using example ftp.
So the question is, how can I make the PC 2 to change color without having someone to sit beside the computer and refresh the page.

How can I remotely tell the server to refresh the website?

Comment: You can't from outside, that would break every security meachanism and also the logic of network topology. But what you _can_ to is use client side logic embedded in said web page that takes care to actively or passively recognize events. Either per simple ajax calls (long poll ajax) or by using "web sockets" which allow two way communitcation. not that such communication is between server and client, _not_ between two clients. So the second system does play an active part, but still only passively waits for events.

Answer (score 1):

To sketch out I would encode a 'pageversion' from php into the javascript on the initial page load:

```
var pageversion=<?php echo $pageversion ?>;
```

Then use EventSource

```
eventer = new EventSource("/eventeg.php");
eventer.onmessage = function (event) {
   var datasent=event.data;
   //use data to compare versions and then reload
};
```

Where the server sends data through a keep-alive connection - simply have the server update the version it sends in realtime and if un-equal do what you need - eg warn the user then have it force refresh after a timeout.
The reload will then align the versions.
You might want to use http-refresh as well as a backup for javascript failure.